# "not at all good" vs "not good at all" - Do they have the same meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning

"The walking is not at all good."

"The walking is not good at all."

I wonder if it is the same or have different meanings like "the walking" in the first sentence is better than in the second one.

Comment: Now, there's an interesting [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=not+at+all+good%2Cnot+good+at+all&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnot%20at%20all%20good%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnot%20good%20at%20all%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they have the same meaning.

Personally, the second one is moderately preferable, as it communicates the core of the message sooner, but semantically, they're identical.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a native speaker. But for some reason I think the 2nd one is the one you should use. It follows the English rhythm. The first one sounds kind of weird.
In order to the meaning I think they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

In "The walking is not at all good", 'at all' is emphasising on 'not' then the adjective is put, giving a meaning that something is not completely good. On the other hand, in  "The walking is not good at all." 'at all'  is put after the whole 
part of sense making sentence.  well, I'm not a native English speaker and the idea only belongs in my mind. Thank you!